# SQL - Copy multiple rows for each row from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I seem to have a relatively simple task to do, but my SQL knowledge is limited and my google fu is failing on me. Although I could work my way around it, by writing a powershell script or fooling around with notepad++, but I'm genuinly interested on how I can achieve this with SQL, especially if the tables become very big and a workaround isn't very feasable anymore.

Simplified, I have two tables:

**Prices**

| Productname | Customer_ID | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| B | 1 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 |
| C | 1 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 |
| D | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| E | 1 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 |

**Customers**

| Name | ID | Customer_Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | ABC |
| C | 3 | ABC |
| D | 4 | ABC |
| E | 5 | ABC |
| F | 6 | ABC |

Now I want to copy (i.e. insert) the 5 rows from the prices table where Customer_ID = 1 back into the prices table for each customer in the customers table where the Customer_Group = ABC. Every time the 5 rows are copied, I also need to set the field Customer_ID to the ID returned by the customers table query.

So the prices table looks like this:

| Productname | Customer_ID | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| B | 1 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 |
| C | 1 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 |
| D | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| E | 1 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 |
| A | 2 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| B | 2 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 |
| C | 2 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 |
| D | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| E | 2 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 |
| A | 3 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| B | 3 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 |
| C | 3 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 |
| D | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| E | 3 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 |

(and so on)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is your table structure?  We cant give best query without actual table structure (with data types/etc).

Comment: Where are the values from Customer ID 2, and 3 coming from? They aren't in your sample data, only Customer 1 is.

Comment: @Larnu, the values for Customer ID 2, 3, etc. need to be copied from Customer 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM CUSTOMERS            
 WHERE CUSTOMERS.NAME IN ('B','C','D','E','F') 
       -- may not be needed if you want all rows from customers table.
```

Will select all the customers you want to work with

Now we just join to the other table to get the data

```
 SELECT *
 FROM CUSTOMERS
 JOIN PRICES ON  PRICES.Customer_ID = 1
 WHERE CUSTOMERS.Customer_Group = 'ABC'
```

Select the columns you need

```
 SELECT PRICES.ProductName, 
        CUSTOMERS.CustomerID,
        PRICES.price1, PRICES.price2, PRICES.price3, PRICES.price4
 FROM CUSTOMERS
 JOIN PRICES ON  PRICES.Customer_ID = 1
 WHERE CUSTOMERS.Customer_Group = 'ABC'
```

If you want to insert that in a table add the insert statement at the start

```
 INSERT INTO PRICES 
      (Productname, Customer_ID, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5)
   SELECT PRICES.ProductName, 
          CUSTOMERS.CustomerID,
          PRICES.price1, PRICES.price2, PRICES.price3, PRICES.price4
   FROM CUSTOMERS
   JOIN PRICES ON  PRICES.Customer_ID = 1
   WHERE CUSTOMERS.Customer_Group = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Your post led me to the answer, so If you could edit your proposed solution to include the insert startement and selection of customers based on Customer_Group, I can accept your answer as the solution.

    INSERT INTO PRICES (Productname, Customer_ID, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5)
    SELECT PRICES.ProductName, 
       CUSTOMERS.CustomerID,
       PRICES.price1, 
    PRICES.price2, 
    PRICES.price3, 
    PRICES.price4, 
    PRICES.price5
     FROM CUSTOMERS
     JOIN PRICES ON PRICES.Customer_ID = 1
     WHERE CUSTOMERS.Customer_Group = 'ABC'

Comment: sure @VolrathTheFallen -- I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

At a total guess, this?

```sql
SELECT P.ProductName,
       P.Customer_ID,
       P.price1,
       P.price2, --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
       P.price3, --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
       P.price4 --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
FROM dbo.Prices P
--WHERE P.Customer = 1 --?
UNION ALL
SELECT P.ProductName,
       C.ID AS CustomerID,
       P.price1,
       P.price2, --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
       P.price3, --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
       P.price4 --This is a denormalised design, and you should fix this
FROM dbo.Prices P
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Customers C;
--WHERE P.Customer = 1 --?
```

Comment: what if customers table has more than just users with customer_id == 1?

Comment: Then it'll cross join them all, @Hogan . The OP *could* add a `WHERE` themselves quite easily. I can only base an answer on the sample data they give.

Comment: That is my point it was in the sample data and the description.  "Now I want to copy the 5 rows from the prices table where Customer_ID = 1 "

Comment: There is only 1 customer in the table `Prices` in their sample, @Hogan . They don't even touch on what they want to do for other customers, so i wouldn't even want to begin to guess. If the OP does want us to guess what we should be doing with these other customers, then I'll vote to close as unclear.

Comment: I just put the quote above?  Is that not a quote from the person you are saying didn't specify?

Comment: Consiering that the sample data only has **one** customer, who has an ID of `1`, "all" and ID `1` are synonym for the sample, @Hogan ... But aghain, `WHERE SomeColumn = 1` is not a difficult concept to grasp. If the OP is really struggling with such things like that, then really they should be reading some tutorials, as both our answers are going to be far beyond their understanding.

Comment: @larnu Hogan's answer seems more parsimonious than yours, eventhough neither provided an insert statement based on the selection of customer_group = ABC. The join-based approach of you both did lead me to the answer I was looking for, so thank you.